# Presto: how to specify time interval using the current date and timezone

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

How to rewrite the following query:

```sql
WHERE (
    parsedTime BETWEEN 
    TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 00:00:00 America/New_York' AND
    TIMESTAMP '2019-11-11 23:59:59 America/New_York'
)
```

but making the interval dynamic: from 14 days ago to `current_date`?

Answer (score 4):

Presto provides quite handy functionality `interval` within [date and time functions and operations](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html).

```sql
-- Creating sample dataset
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    'engineering' as department,
    ARRAY[
        TIMESTAMP '2019-11-05 00:00:00', 
        TIMESTAMP '2018-10-29 00:00:00'
    ] as parsedTime_array
)
SELECT department, parsedTime FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(parsedTime_array) as t(parsedTime)

-- Filtering records for the past 14 days from current_date
WHERE(
    parsedTime > current_date - interval '14' day
)
```

Result

```
    | department    | parsedTime
---------------------------------------
1   | engineering   | 2019-11-05 00:00:00.000
```

### Update 2019-11-11

**Note:** `current_date` returns the current date as of the start of the query. I think, Athena would always use UTC time, but not 100% sure. So to extract current date in a particular time zone, I'd suggest to use timestamps with time zone conversion. Although it is true that

```
current_timestamp = current_timestamp at TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
```

since `AT TIME ZONE` represents the same instant in time but differs only in the time zone used to print them. However the following is not always true due to 5 hour offset.

```
DATE(current_timestamp) = DATE(current_timestamp at TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')
```

This can be easily verified with:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    ARRAY[
        TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 23:59:59 UTC',
        TIMESTAMP '2019-10-30 00:00:00 UTC',
        TIMESTAMP '2019-10-30 04:59:59 UTC',
        TIMESTAMP '2019-10-30 05:00:00 UTC'
    ] as parsedTime_array
)
SELECT
    parsedTime AS "Time UTC",
    DATE(parsedTime) AS "Date UTC",
    DATE(parsedTime at TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') AS "Date NY",
    to_unixtime(DATE(parsedTime)) AS "Unix UTC",
    to_unixtime(DATE(parsedTime at TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')) AS "Unix NY"
FROM
    dataset,
    UNNEST(parsedTime_array) as t(parsedTime)
```

**Result.** Here we can see that **2** NY timestamps fall into `2019-10-29` and `2019-10-30` whereas for UTC timestamps it is only 1 and 3 respectively.

```
 Time UTC                    | Date UTC   | Date NY    | Unix UTC   | Unix NY    
-----------------------------|------------|------------|------------|------------
 2019-10-29 23:59:59.000 UTC | 2019-10-29 | 2019-10-29 | 1572307200 | 1572307200 
 2019-10-30 00:00:00.000 UTC | 2019-10-30 | 2019-10-29 | 1572393600 | 1572307200 
 2019-10-30 04:59:59.000 UTC | 2019-10-30 | 2019-10-30 | 1572393600 | 1572393600 
 2019-10-30 05:00:00.000 UTC | 2019-10-30 | 2019-10-30 | 1572393600 | 1572393600
```

Now, let's fast forward a month. There was a change to winter time in [NY on 3rd or November 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york-state). However, timestamp in UTC format is not affected by it. Therefore:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    ARRAY[
        TIMESTAMP '2019-11-29 23:59:59 UTC',
        TIMESTAMP '2019-11-30 00:00:00 UTC',
        TIMESTAMP '2019-11-30 04:59:59 UTC',
        TIMESTAMP '2019-11-30 05:00:00 UTC'
    ] as parsedTime_array
)
SELECT
    parsedTime AS "Time UTC",
    DATE(parsedTime) AS "Date UTC",
    DATE(parsedTime at TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') AS "Date NY",
    to_unixtime(DATE(parsedTime)) AS "Unix UTC",
    to_unixtime(DATE(parsedTime at TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')) AS "Unix NY"
FROM
    dataset,
    UNNEST(parsedTime_array) as t(parsedTime)
```

**Result.** Here we can see that **3** NY timestamps fall into `2019-11-29` and **1** falling into  `2019-11-30`, whereas for UTC timestamps ratio of 1/3 remained the same.

```
 Time UTC                    | Date UTC   | Date NY    | Unix UTC   | Unix NY    
-----------------------------|------------|------------|------------|------------
 2019-11-29 23:59:59.000 UTC | 2019-11-29 | 2019-11-29 | 1574985600 | 1574985600 
 2019-11-30 00:00:00.000 UTC | 2019-11-30 | 2019-11-29 | 1575072000 | 1574985600 
 2019-11-30 04:59:59.000 UTC | 2019-11-30 | 2019-11-29 | 1575072000 | 1574985600 
 2019-11-30 05:00:00.000 UTC | 2019-11-30 | 2019-11-30 | 1575072000 | 1575072000
```

Furthermore, different countries switch to winter/summer time on different dates. For instance in 2019, London (UK) moved clock 1 hour back on [27 October 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london), whereas NY (USA) moved clock 1 hour back on [3 November 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york-state).

Comment: parsedTime is stored in UTC timezone, this query doesn't convert current_date to America/New_York

Comment: Then you would need to use `at TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'` for both timestamps in `WHERE` clause. See updated answer

Comment: It seem like parsedTime at TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' > Date() is the same as parsedTime > Date(), so the results are starting from 00:00:00 UTC, not 05:00:00 UTC. This  clause worked for me: parsedTime > CAST(CONCAT(date_format(current_date - interval '13' day, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' 00:00:00 America/New_York') AS TIMESTAMP)